# Uniqueness of projection under spectral norm

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, semidefinite-programming, spectral-radius

I am considering 
$$
\min_{M\in \mathcal{M}} \|X - M\|:=x \neq 0,
$$
where $X$, $M$ are $m\times n$ matrices, $\|\cdot\|$ is spectral norm and $\mathcal{M}$ is a matrix subspace. I wonder to what extent the solutions are unique, i.e. what can we say about the set
$$
\mathcal{M}^* = \{M|\|X - M\|=x\}.
$$ 
Currently, I only know it is a convex set. For $M_1, M_2 \in \mathcal{M}^*$, let $M = p M_1 + (1-p) M_2$, $p \in (0,1)$. For any vector $v$, using Cauchy's inequality, we have
$$
v^T(X - M)^T(X - M)v \leq x^2,
$$
thus $M \in \mathcal{M}^*$. Moreover, the equality holds only when
$$
(X - M_1)v = (X - M_2)v = u,~~~~s.t.~u^T u = x^2.   
$$
I wonder whether there are more properties I could say about this set, e.g. its dimension/the properties of the common eigenvectors/the condition under which the solution is unique.